# Using a static Comparator to sort a BSTree

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I have some school work where I have `BTree<E>` class, now I'm having to do a `BSTree<E>` class that extends `BTree<E>`. The `BSTree` should be a sorted `BTree`.

The teacher recommended using a static `Comparator` that could sort all the elements by the required attribute. He gave us some code to go by, but don't quite understand how to use static generic variables in a class. I know what static does, but I don't no know how to get around the problem.

Here is my code:

```
public class BSTree<E> extends BTree<E>{

    List<E> duplicates;
    static Comparator<E> comp = new NasComparator<E>();

    private static class NasComparator<E extends Comparable> implements Comparator<E>{
        @Override
        public int compare(E o1, E o2){
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should first probably rename `BTree` to `BinaryTree`.

Comment: @Swapnil: Why? B-tree is a very specific data structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree (Although admittedly B-trees are naturally sorted already...)

Comment: Sorry, got confused completely when I read it the first time.

Comment: Does the above compile? The type parameter `E` on `BSTree` does not extend `Comparable`, yet you use it with `NasComparator` which requires it to.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a bit off topic, but I think it worth take a look.

Your Comparator is simply useless.  Normally we need a Comparator because the target object to be compared are not Comparable, or the default comparing does not fit our use.

However, if you simply make a Comparator that have restriction of E extends Comparable, and the compare logic is simply `return a.compareTo(b)`, then why not simply compare directly?  Something like

```
public class BSTree<E extends Comparable> extends BTree<E>{
}
```

Your sorting simply make use of the Comparable#compareTo method.

If you want to optionally let user provide Comparator, refer to the way done in TreeMap.  Basic idea is, if comparator is provided, then use the comparator, if not, then cast the entry to Comparable, and do the comparison.

---

If you insists to use a Comparator (that's what you mentioned in your comment, though I don't get the reason behind it), as you needs your elements to be `Comparable`, so you need to put this restriction in your generic type param, and simply make a Comparator to compare for "Comparable".

```
public class BSTree<E extends Comparable> extends BTree<E>{

    static Comparator<Comparable> comp = new ComparableComparator();

    private static class ComparableComparator implements Comparator<Comparable>{
        @Override
        public int compare(Comparable o1, Comparable o2){
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    }
}
```

It look weird but that's what you ask for.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm required to have an object that is used for sorting the BSTree. That's what I'm having problems with.

Comment: I don't get your point.  How's your sorting be done? You can simply sort without any comparator as your elements extends Comparable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little tricky because you define two `E`:

- one in `BSTree<E>`, which the static variable `comp` uses: that cannot compile because `E` is only known at the instance level and can't be used in a static context.
- one in `NasComparator<E extends Comparable>`, the scope of which is that nested class only

My understanding is that you want to sort your list based on the properties of the items stored in it. You don't need an extra class for that and can use a Comparator. Imagine that you want to sort some Item based on their property field, you could do:

```
class Item {
    String property;
}

BSTree<Item> tree = ...;
tree.sort(new Comparator<Item> () {
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        //you should handle the null case
        return o1.property.compareTo(o2.property);
    }
}
```

And in your BSTree, you need to implement that sorting operation, using the provided comparator.

Now you can declare your comparator a static variable wherever you want to be able to reuse it when you need it.